# PHP Merge by values in same array

Tags: php

So I have this array in PHP.

```
$arr = [
    [ 'sections' => [1], 'id' => 1 ],
    [ 'sections' => [2], 'id' => 1 ],
    [ 'sections' => [3], 'id' => NULL ],
    [ 'sections' => [4], 'id' => 4 ],
    [ 'sections' => [5], 'id' => 4 ],
    [ 'sections' => [6], 'id' => 4 ]
];
```

I want to merge on 'id' and get something like

```
$arr = [
    [ 'sections' => [1, 2], 'id' => 1 ],
    [ 'sections' => [3], 'id' => NULL ],
    [ 'sections' => [4, 5, 6], 'id' => 4 ]
];
```

Just struggling to get my head around this one. Any Ideas

Comment: This is unclear. Maybe different keynames would be helpful?

Comment: Where are you getting the square brackets from. This is the complete wrogn format for an array!

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea: Did you try it?  PHP 5.4.

Comment: This is using shorthand for arrays. The key names are for show here.

Comment: @AbraCadaver, didn't know this was valid for 5.4...learn something everyday!

Comment: Are they always going to be in that order, i.e. all of the ids grouped like that.

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea Yes they will.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created this quick function that might work for you

```
<?php 
// Your array
$arr = array(
        array( 'elem1' => 1, 'elem2' => 1 ),
        array( 'elem1' => 2, 'elem2' => 1 ),
        array( 'elem1' => 3, 'elem2' => NULL ),
        array( 'elem1' => 4, 'elem2' => 4 ),
        array( 'elem1' => 5, 'elem2' => 4 ),
        array( 'elem1' => 6, 'elem2' => 4 )
);
print_r($arr);

function mergeBy($arr, $elem2 = 'elem2') {
    $result = array();

    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if (empty($result[$item[$elem2]])) {
            // for new items (elem2), just add it in with index of elem2's value to start
            $result[$item[$elem2]] = $item;
        } else {
            // for non-new items (elem2) merge any other values (elem1)
            foreach ($item as $key => $val) {
                if ($key != $elem2) {
                    // cast elem1's as arrays, just incase you were lazy like me in the declaration of the array
                    $result[$item[$elem2]][$key] = $result[$item[$elem2]][$key] = array_merge((array)$result[$item[$elem2]][$key],(array)$val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // strip out the keys so that you dont have the elem2's values all over the place
    return array_values($result);
}

print_r(mergeBy($arr));
?>
```

Hopefully it'll work for more than 2 elements, and you can choose what to sort on also....